# how to zoom open street map

Tags: android, android-mapview

How do I zoom openstreet map? My code below only has a mapview.builinzoom control(TRUE)

How do I give my level of zoom like in googlemapview there is a function like

```
MapController mc = mapView.getController();
mc.setZoom(15);
```

So how do I add this type function in openstreet map so when application is launched it's already zoomed and show me proper result?

```
import org.osmdroid.DefaultResourceProxyImpl;
import org.osmdroid.ResourceProxy;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;

import com.google.android.maps.MapController;


import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 MyItemizedOverlay myItemizedOverlay = null;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


    Drawable marker=getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_big_on);
    int markerWidth = marker.getIntrinsicWidth();
    int markerHeight = marker.getIntrinsicHeight();
    marker.setBounds(0, markerHeight, markerWidth, 0);

    ResourceProxy resourceProxy = new       
   DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());

    myItemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(marker, resourceProxy);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myItemizedOverlay);

    GeoPoint myPoint1 = new GeoPoint(24.893379000000000000, 67.028060900000010000);
    myItemizedOverlay.addItem(myPoint1, "myPoint1", "myPoint1");
    GeoPoint myPoint2 = new GeoPoint(24.824796300000000000, 67.031565699999990000);
    myItemizedOverlay.addItem(myPoint2, "myPoint2", "myPoint2");


    } 

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

See the API, specifically the [IMapView](http://osmdroid.googlecode.com/svn/branches/release_3_0_5/osmdroid-android/src/org/osmdroid/api/IMapView.java) and [IMapController](http://osmdroid.googlecode.com/svn/branches/release_3_0_5/osmdroid-android/src/org/osmdroid/api/IMapController.java) interfaces. You should get something like this:

```
mapView.getController().setZoom(16);
```

Comment: u mean disable this line?

 mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

Comment: No. Add this at the end of your onCreate method.

Comment: not working when add this line map is disbale onl y green screen show

Answer (score 1):

U disable for this line and runs for ur application,

```
 mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Comment: For me this is not properly zooming the map.

Answer (score -1):

Don't create your mapview in xml, in xml not worked drag map and zoom controls for me.

But, creating programmatically like this example, works for me.

https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/branches/rotation/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/org/osmdroid/MapActivity.java?r=914